# Failed to install redis-commander in debian strech

Tags: npm, redis, debian

I tried to install redis-commander but when i run redis-commander i am getting the following errors

```
redis-commander 
{ Error: ENOENT : no such file or directory, open '/root/.redis-commander'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/root/.redis-commander' }
No config found or was invalid.
Using default configuration.
No Save: true
listening on  0.0.0.0 : 8081
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8081
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1366:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1407:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1522:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
root@debian:/home/midhun#
```

Answer (score 0):

Means address (port) already in use by some other process